# Changing PHP GD Library to increase image quality

Tags: php

We implemented a parametric image generator that creates images that contain texts with dynamic sizes using the PHP GD Library.

In order to create a printable image, we need the increase the image quality to 500 DPI.

Can anyone give us guidance on how to extend this?

Comment: In order to change what you have, we need to see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

imagejpeg[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) takes an argument for image quality. It defaults to 75, but you can increase it up to a maximum of 100. For example:

```
imagejpeg($canvas, NULL, 90);
```

However, for generated graphics with lots of continuous colours and sharp lines, JPEG is probably not the best choice. PNGs are more well-suited to these sorts of images, and will probably give you perfect quality at a smaller size. imagepng[docs] has a few options, but the defaults should be fine:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($canvas);
```

You're using `imagecreate`[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) to make the image in the first place. This creates a "pallet-based" image: one that can only use a limited number of colours. This matches the lower quality of a GIF or an 8-bit PNG, but because you're not using those formats you should use `imagecreatetruecolor`[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) instead. So far, your image is very simple and this might not make a difference, but it will matter if you're generating more complicated images.

If you make these two changes, your images will be sure to have perfect quality.